# How to execute raw SQL in Asp.net core using repository pattern

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am trying to execute a `SELECT` SQL statement in ASP.net core using repository pattern where I will pass the statement to the implementation of the repository interface and then I want to get the list produced from this statement.
The following code snippet shows the repo interface

```
 public interface IRepository<T> where T : class
    {
        List<T> GetAll(Expression<Func<T, DateTime?>> filter = null);
        IQueryable<T> Find(Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression);
        void Add(T entity);
        void AddRange(IEnumerable<T> entities);
        void Update(T entity);
        void UpdateRange(IEnumerable<T> entities);
        void Remove(T entity);
        void RemoveRange(IEnumerable<T> entities);
        List<T> sql(string statment);
    }
```

The implementation of the **sql method** in the interface is as shown:

```
public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
    {

        private APPDBContext context;
        private readonly DbSet<T> dbSet;
      
        public Repository(APPDBContext _context) 
        {
            dbSet = _context.Set<T>();
            context = _context;
        }
        
         public List<T> sql(string state)
       {
           return dbSet.FromSqlRaw(state).ToList();
       }
}
```

to use this method a component class is created using unit of work as shown:

```
public class MyComponent : ComponentBase
    {
       
         public List<Entity> Search(string sql)
         {
             try
             {
               List<Entity> result = base.UnitOfWork.MyComponent.sql(sql);
               return result;
              
           }
           catch (Exception ex)
             {
                 return null;
             }
         }

    }
```

Where the ComponentBase class is as shown:

```
public class ComponentBase
    {
        public UofW UnitOfWork { get; private set; }
        public ComponentBase() 
        {
            if(UnitOfWork == null)
                UnitOfWork = new UofW(new APPDBContext());
        }

        public int Save() 
        {
            int ret = UnitOfWork.Save();
            UnitOfWork.Dispose();
            return ret;
        }
    }
```

Where the UofW class is as shown:

```
public class UofW : IUofW
    {
        private readonly APPDBContext context;

        public UofW(APPDBContext _context)
        {
            context = _context;
        }
          
        private IRepository<Entity> _MyComponent;
        public IRepository<Entity> MyComponent
        {
            get
            {
                if(_MyComponent == null)
                    _MyComponent = new Repository<Entity>(context);
                return _MyComponent;
            }
        }
         
         

        public int Save()
        {
            return context.SaveChanges();
        }

        private bool disposed = false;

        protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (!this.disposed)
            {
                if (disposing)
                {
                    context.Dispose();
                }
            }
            this.disposed = true;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Dispose(true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }

    }
```

And the IUofW is:

```
    public interface IUofW : IDisposable
    {
        IRepository<Entity> MyComponent { get; }

        int Save();

       
    }
```

Finally, I send a request to my controller to form my statement and execute it as shown:

```
        [HttpPost("Search")]
        public ActionResult Search(Entity object)
        {
            var response = new Response<Entity>();
            var MyComponent = new MyComponent();
            if (object == null)
            {
                response.DidError = true;
                response.ErrorMessage = "invalid data";

                return StatusCode((int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, response);
            }

             try
             {
                string cndtn = "";
                 if (object.column1 != null && object.column1 != "") { if (cndtn == "") { cndtn = cndtn + ""; } else { cndtn = cndtn + " and "; } cndtn = cndtn + " column1='" + object.column1 + "' "; };
                if (object.column2 != null && object.column2 != "") { if (cndtn == "") { cndtn = cndtn + ""; } else { cndtn = cndtn + " and "; } cndtn = cndtn + " Brd_No='" + object.column2 + "' "; };
                if (object.column3 != null && object.column3 != "") { if (cndtn == "") { cndtn = cndtn + ""; } else { cndtn = cndtn + " and "; } cndtn = cndtn + " column3='" + object.column3 + "' "; };
            
                string Sql = "SELECT * FROM MyTable";
                if(cndtn == "") { Sql = Sql + "";} else { Sql = Sql + " WHERE " + cndtn; }

                response.ModelList = MyComponent.Search(Sql);
                
                return Ok(response);
            }
             catch (Exception ex)
             {
                 response.DidError = true;
                 response.ErrorMessage = ex.Message;

                 return StatusCode((int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, response);
             }
        }
```

The SQL Statement is formed correctly but when I pass it to the Search method the response is null which means that my statement is not executed...so what is wrong with my code and how can I execute the statement??

Comment: can your please share code of  ```AsstComponent.Search(Sql); ```

Comment: Sorry it was a mistake and I modified it....There is no `AsstComponent` it's `MyComponent.Search(Sql);` .....Forgive me

Comment: It seems you want to achieve the same as "[Build a linq query based on specific criteria c#"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6590174/build-a-linq-query-based-on-specific-criteria-c-sharp). Also, take a look at [this](https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library) and [this](http://tomasp.net/blog/dynamic-linq-queries.aspx/).

Comment: change this ```base.UnitOfWork.MyComponent.FromSql("SQL_SCRIPT").ToList();``` on MyComponent, it should work...